# Magento redrecting from Observer.php only on specific front-end router

Tags: magento

I have to redirect users that tries to visit URL's from an old website.

I have built a custom module.

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_OldWebUrlRedirect>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_OldWebUrlRedirect>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <movie>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Company_OldWebUrlRedirect</module>
                    <frontName>movie</frontName>
                </args>
            </movie>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <oldweburlredirect>
                <class>Company_OldWebUrlRedirect_Model</class>
            </oldweburlredirect>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <company_oldweburlredirect>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>oldweburlredirect/observer</class>
                        <method>assetRedirection</method>
                    </company_oldweburlredirect>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

My Observer.php fires fine. However, this approach means that the observer is used for every single page load on the website.
Is there a way to only use the Observer.php when 
**http://somecompany.com/movie/** or eg. **http://somecompany.com/movie/some-movie-name** is requested?

The idea in the end is to make the observer redirect **http://somecompany.com/movie/some-movie-name** to **http://somecompany/some-movie-name.html**

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered doing this outside of Magento using a .htaccess rewrite rule?

If your URL's are consistent (ie the only different being the lack of the /movie/, then this might be a much better option).

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/movie/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

**Note that the above htaccess is untested**